# Javascript - Creating event listener that returns id of dynamically generated content

Tags: javascript, html

my main project is too complicated to show here so I created a small script demonstrating the problem I am working on. In simple terms, I need to create a button that once clicked, generates a button that also has an event listener that returns that button's id to the console.
See code below:

```js
button_number = 0

create_buttons = document.getElementById('create_buttons')
div = document.getElementById('div')

create_buttons.addEventListener('click', e=>{
  button_number += 1
  new_button = document.createElement('button')
  new_button.setAttribute('id', 'button'+button_number)
  new_button.innerHTML = 'What number am I?'
  new_button.addEventListener('click', show_button_number)
  div.appendChild(new_button)
})

function show_button_number () {
  let number = button_number
  button = document.getElementById('button' + number)
  console.log(button.id) 
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
     <button id="create_buttons">Create a button!</button>
</div>
```

As written, all generated buttons return the button id of the most recently generated button versus their own id. Is there anyway I can change the anonymous function to return the button id of the button that was clicked? In order to integrate this into my main project, I need to create the event listener for the dynamically generated buttons using an anonymous function.

Comment: `Is there anyway I can change the anonymous function to return the button id of the button that was clicked?` Where do you want the value to be returned to? The event listener is calling your callback function. I think you are confusing something,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a higher-order function, one that takes the current button number as an argument and returns a function using it:

```
const makeListener = num => () => {
  const button = document.getElementById('button' + num)
  console.log(button.id) 
};
```

```
new_button.addEventListener('click', makeListener(button_number))
```

Or, you may not need the ID at all, just pass the element itself:

```
create_buttons.addEventListener('click', e=>{
    const btn = div.appendChild(document.createElement('button'));
    btn.textContent = 'What number am I?'
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log(new_button);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The major way to do that is to use event delegation mechanim

```js
const divParent = document.getElementById('div')

var button_number = 0


divParent.addEventListener('click', e =>
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('button')) return // ignore clicks from other things
  
  if (e.target.id === 'create_buttons')
    {
    let new_button = document.createElement('button')
    new_button.id          = 'button' + ++button_number
    new_button.textContent = 'What number am I?' 
    divParent.appendChild(new_button)
    }
  else
    {
    console.clear()
    console.log( e.target.id )
    }
  })
```

```html
<div id="div">
  <button id="create_buttons">Create a button!</button>
</div>
```